# How values method work in enum

Tags: java

In Enum how values() method work ?

what logic behind values() method ?

In my project we cache all enum data in Map as follow :

```
public enum Actions {
CREATE("create"),
UPDATE("update"),
DELETE("delete"),
ACTIVE("active"),
INACTIVE("inactive"),
MANAGE_ORDER("manage"),
;


private static Map<String, Actions> actionMap;
static {
    actionMap = new HashMap<String, Actions>(values().length);
    for(Actions action : values()) {
        actionMap.put(action.getName(), action);
    }
}

public static Actions fromName(String name) {
    if(name == null) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return actionMap.get(name);
}
private String name;

private Actions(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

}
```

Is this best practice for use enum ?

Comment: It is a standard idiom if your enum is often queried by its name to make the `fromName` method more efficient.

Comment: can I make fromName more efficient for Actions enum in code example ?

Comment: What do you mean by more efficient? Performance wise it is an O(1) operation (and so is value of).

Comment: Yes Performance wise, If Actions enum has more data around 255 which one use value Of or HashMap

Comment: `valueOf` uses a HashMap too so performance will be identical and as good as you can get. If `valueOf` does what you need, by all means use it, if not your custom `fromName` method is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In Enum how values() method work ?

Read the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

> The enum declaration defines a class (called an enum type). The enum class body can include methods and other fields. **The compiler automatically adds some special methods when it creates an enum. For example, they have a static values method that returns an array containing all of the values of the enum in the order they are declared.** This method is commonly used in combination with the for-each construct to iterate over the values of an enum type.

Another thing to note is that , if you use enum as keys , better to use [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html).

> A specialized Map implementation for use with enum type keys. All of the keys in an enum map must come from a single enum type that is specified, explicitly or implicitly, when the map is created. Enum maps are represented internally as arrays. **This representation is extremely compact and efficient.**

Comment: the keys are strings, not enum.

Comment: @assylias Sorry , I saw that now !

Answer (score 2):

Not great practice. Apart from `MANAGE_ORDER`, you could replace all that crap with this:

```
public static Action fromName(String name) {
    try {
        return valueOf(name.toUpperCase());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Also, naming your field `name` is a poor choice, because all enums implicitly have:

```
public String name();
```

which returns the enum constant name as a String.

Comment: And if `name` is not a valid name, you will throw an exception, the  op's code will return null.

Comment: @assylias hmmmm. I'm trying to wage a jihad against useless code here... How about now?

Comment: I agree with you that `valueOf` should be used when possible. But if the strings different from the enum constant names, the OP's approach is fine.